# Content Encoding Error but only for the first time when you visit the page on Drupal

Tags: encoding, drupal-7, gzip, content-encoding

When i visit it for the first time this error shows up. If i reload the page again this error is gone.

We have same website setup in UAT and in DEV but they do not have any such errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a lot it was discovered that this is a production level issue and as shown in screenshot below. This option should be untik and the issue will disappear.

[image]